# unnamed namespace adding to xmlnode

Tags: c#, namespaces

I want to add an unnamed namespace to my root xmlnode.  how do I do this?

error message---

The local name for elements or attributes cannot be null or an empty string.

```
        System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

        XmlNode ShipmentReceiptNotification0Node = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ShipmentReceiptNotification", "", "namespacename");

        ShipmentReceiptNotification0Node.InnerText = String.Empty;
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(ShipmentReceiptNotification0Node);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the other 2 argument override for [CreateElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1k08cbx.aspx).

```
var node = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ShipmentReceiptNotification", "namespacename");
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code like this:

```
XmlNode ShipmentReceiptNotification0Node = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ShipmentReceiptNotification", "namespacename");
```